# JavaScript Fetch API - Why does it return undefined when executed in browser console?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, console, console.log

This is the local host server I am running which gives the status of server.

```py
import flask as Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/health_check', methods=['GET'])
def health_status():

data = {'status': 'server is live'}

    resp = app.response_class(
    status=200,
    response= json.dumps(data),
    mimetype='application/json'
        )
    
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001, host='0.0.0.0',)
```

Now I am trying to fetch the data from the browser using JavaScript in the console.

```js
let path = "http://localhost:5001/health_check";

var init_var = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
};

const GetHealthStatus = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(path, init_var);
  const myJson = response.text(); //extract JSON from the http response
  return myJson
};

var health_status = await GetHealthStatus();
console.log(health_status);
```

It says `undefined`.

If do `http://localhost:5001/health_check` in the browser and then run the same JavaScript code, I am getting this output.

```js
{ "status": "server is live!" }
```

I am trying to understand what is happening at the browser and on the server end. Could not able to find any article to understand it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the console when you load the site? That `await GetHealthStatus()` looks suspicious because it's not clear that it's inside an `async` function.

Comment: Pointy 'await GetHealthStatus() is not inside the async for your information. it works for my friends same setup. but something going in the browser i guess. any ideas do let me know

Comment: JavaScript will give you a syntax error if you use `await` not inside of an `async` function.

Comment: I don't believe it does if you run it in the console, as he's doing here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myJson = response.text(); //extract JSON from the http response
```

You're missing an `await` here in front of `response.text()`. It [returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried it. I am still getting no response.

Comment: Write `(async()=>{` at the top of your code and `})();` at the bottom.

Comment: As insisted i have made the modification. I am not getting any response still. will their be problem with some chrome settings? any guess. Because it works in my colleague Laptop

Comment: Try `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`.

Comment: Actually just use the empty object `{}` instead of `init_var` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi GirkovArpa. I have tried your suggestion . I am getting an error as below 'Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/health_check' from origin 'chrome-search://local-ntp' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'

Answer (score 0):

You need to import json from flask:

```
from flask import json
```

Here is a complete code that worked in my environment:

```
from flask import json
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
#...
@app.route('/health-check')
def health():
    data = {'status': 'server is live'}

    resp = app.response_class(
    status=200,
    response= json.dumps(data),
    mimetype='application/json'
        )
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Here is the output from curl command:

```
curl -I http://localhost:5000/health-check

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.5 Python/2.7.16
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 03:02:25 GMT
```

Output from curl with server running with python3:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 707
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.2
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 03:18:40 GM
```

Here is the output from my `flask` server:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 00:02:04] "GET /health-check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 00:02:25] "HEAD /health-check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```